# Creating Intent using an ArrayList

Tags: android, android-intent, arraylist, start-activity

So I have an ArrayList, and I would like to create intent and switch activities using this piece of code (in ListAdapter class):

```
for (int i = 0; i <= activityList.size(); i++){

    if (position == i){
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, (activityList.get(i).getName()).class);
        context.startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

I am getting an 'identifier expected' error around .class.

I do have a working piece of code, that does what I want, but I have to specify the class (which isn't what I want) here:

```
if (position == 0) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, NextActivity.class);
    context.startActivity(intent);
}
```

Not exactly sure why the 1st piece of code isn't working. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: 1) i dont think you need = sign in the <= list.size(). 2) what is activityList? I know its a List... but a List of what? Strings? Because that will not work.... becuase thens it "nextactivity".class

Comment: Yes, it's a list of Strings. The quotes mess it up?

Comment: uhhhh....yeah. because NextActivity isn't a String.... its a filename.

Comment: Ah, not sure why I didn't think about that. Thanks, gonna change some things up then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to pass **Class** type as Intent's second parameter, where you are using

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, (activityList.get(i).getName()).class);
```

in this type of case you would need `List<Class>` like

```
List<Class> activityList = Arrays.asList(ActivityA.class, ActivityB.class, ActivityC.class);
```

the use it like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, activityList.get(i));
```

I'd suggest to change your `List<String>` to `List<Class>`.

Comment: Did you get the solution?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to this job is to convert your String to class. Here is a code to do that-

```
for (int i = 0; i <= activityList.size(); i++){
    if (position == i){
        String activity = "YourPackageName."+arrayList.get(i).getName();
        Intent intent = null;

        try {
            intent = new Intent(context, Class.forName(activity));
        } 
        catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        context.startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

The model should return the class name without class keyword. Eg:-Main2Activity

Comment: I tried that, but its giving me this error 'Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.content.Intent.migrateExtraStreamToClipData()' on a null object reference'

Comment: Plz send the model and what type of data are you adding in array list @SlavictheSlavic

Comment: I'm just sending an array list of 4 strings to my ListAdapter. Also I had to change your 'arrayList' to 'activityList', I believe that's what you meant.

Comment: Your array list must be of type object. Also can you mention the strings that you are passing to the list ?

Comment: Ah, alright. I'm just passing ("one", "two", "three", "four") simple test strings

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176674/discussion-between-raj-and-slavic-the-slavic).